# Add image annotations to bar plots

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

So, for example, let's say I have some data

```
countries = ["Norway", "Spain", "Germany", "Canada", "China"]
valuesA = [20, 15, 30, 5, 26]
valuesB = [1, 5, 3, 6, 2]
```

and I do wanna plot them like

[image: this].

How do I put those flag pictures in the graph (if it is even possbile)?
And secondly, how can I automate this?

Answer (score 24):

This solution will work for axes level plots produced with `matplotlib`, `seaborn`, and `pandas.DataFrame.plot`.

The main idea would be to separate the problem into small pieces:

1. Get the flag as an array into the script. E.g.

   ```
    def get_flag(name):
        path = "path/to/flag/{}.png".format(name)
        im = plt.imread(path)
        return im
   ```
2. Position an image at a certain position in a plot. This can be accomplished using an [`OffsetImage`](https://matplotlib.org/api/offsetbox_api.html#matplotlib.offsetbox.OffsetImage). An example can be found on the [matplotlib page](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/demo_annotation_box.html). Best use a function which takes the name of the country and the position as arguments and generates an `AnnotationBbox` with the `OffsetImage` inside.
3. Drawing the barplot using `ax.bar`. To set  the country names as ticklabels, use `ax.set_ticklabels(countries)`. Then for every country place the [`OffsetImage`](https://matplotlib.org/api/offsetbox_api.html#matplotlib.offsetbox.OffsetImage) from above using a loop.

`(coord, 0)` and `xybox=(0., -16.)` can be adjusted to place the image annotations at any location.

The final result may then look something like this:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.offsetbox import OffsetImage,AnnotationBbox

def get_flag(name):
    path = "data/flags/Flags/flags/flags/24/{}.png".format(name.title())
    im = plt.imread(path)
    return im

def offset_image(coord, name, ax):
    img = get_flag(name)
    im = OffsetImage(img, zoom=0.72)
    im.image.axes = ax

    ab = AnnotationBbox(im, (coord, 0),  xybox=(0., -16.), frameon=False,
                        xycoords='data',  boxcoords="offset points", pad=0)

    ax.add_artist(ab)
    

countries = ["Norway", "Spain", "Germany", "Canada", "China"]
valuesA = [20, 15, 30, 5, 26]
 

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.bar(range(len(countries)), valuesA, width=0.5,align="center")
ax.set_xticks(range(len(countries)))
ax.set_xticklabels(countries)
ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', pad=26)

for i, c in enumerate(countries):
    offset_image(i, c, ax)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Source of flags: https://github.com/google/region-flags or 
https://github.com/hjnilsson/country-flags

Comment: How would you change this example to work if you wanted to ONLY use the flags, and not the country names? Would you still have to use this approach or could you use the images as the x tick labels directly somehow?

Comment: Could you specify all the arguments for the function AnnotationBbox more in detail ? Like the xy values are used to align the image above the label.

Comment: You changed the Y values so that Germany now scores highest (in whatever unit it is measured ;-)