# How to use images as x-axis labels in Matplotlib python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was trying to use country flags as x-axis label and encountered this
nice [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44246650/automating-bar-charts-plotting-to-show-country-flags-as-ticklabels). This gives some hints how to draw the plot, but I am having difficulty moving the flages around the axes.

So far I have done this:

```
def get_flag(name):
    path = "flags/{}.png".format(name)
    im = plt.imread(path)
    return im

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from matplotlib.patches import Circle
from matplotlib.offsetbox import (TextArea, DrawingArea, OffsetImage,
                                  AnnotationBbox)
from matplotlib.cbook import get_sample_data


# axes
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# data
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
y = [20, 15, 30, 5, 26]

countries = ['','ad','ae','af','ag','ai']

# bar plot
ax.bar(x,y)
ax.set_xticklabels(countries)

# image
arr_img = get_flag('ad')

# add image
imagebox = OffsetImage(arr_img, zoom=0.4)
imagebox.image.axes = ax

xy = (0.6, 0.1)
ab = AnnotationBbox(imagebox, xy,
                    xybox=(1.4, -0.3),
                    xycoords='data',
                    boxcoords="offset points",
                    pad=0.5,
                    arrowprops=dict(
                        arrowstyle="->",
                        connectionstyle="angle,angleA=0,angleB=90,rad=3")
                    )

ax.add_artist(ab)
plt.tight_layout()
```

The flages can be found [here](https://github.com/hjnilsson/country-flags/tree/master/png100px).

I have them in local folder `flags/*.png`.

My result:
[image]

Related links:

https://github.com/hjnilsson/country-flags
[Automating bar charts plotting to show country flags as ticklabels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44246650/automating-bar-charts-plotting-to-show-country-flags-as-ticklabels)

**Problem**
I am having difficulty changing x,y coordinates of flag. I want them
all below the tick labels.

Comment: I provided the full working code at the [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44264051/4124317).

Comment: Thanks, and Upvoted!