# Use SVG as tick label in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is it possible to use a SVG image as tick label in Matplotlib?

I am trying to do something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44246650/automating-bar-charts-plotting-to-show-country-flags-as-ticklabels) but my images are SVG.

Do I have to convert all images to PNG for the above answer to work or can I use SVG directly?

Comment: Matplotlib cannot read svg images. So in case you want to use matplotlib, and apply the linked solution you need to  convert to png first (or in fact any other format that matplotlib can read).

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it answered your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer **yes**, you do need to convert them first.

---

#### Long answer

From the [`matplotlib.image`](https://matplotlib.org/api/image_api.html#matplotlib.image.imread) page,

> ### Notes
>
> Matplotlib can only read PNGs natively. Further image formats are supported via the optional dependency on Pillow.

A list of supported file formats for Pillow's current stable release can be found [here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html) (including read only and write only supported), at the time of writing this, the list of fully supported formats is

1. BMP
2. DIB
3. EPS
4. GIF
5. ICNS
6. ICO
7. IM
8. JPEG
9. JPEG 2000
10. MSP
11. PCX
12. PNG
13. PPM
14. SGI
15. SPIDER
16. TGA
17. TIFF
18. WEBP
19. XBM

If you want to use your SVG images they will need to first be converted to PNG if your matplotlib installation is not using Pillow and any of the above if it is.