# How can I add images to bars in axes (matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, figure, axes

I want to add flag images such as below to my bar chart:

[image]

I have tried AnnotationBbox but that shows with a square outline. Can anyone tell how to achieve this exactly as above image?

Edit:

Below is my code

```
ax.barh(y = y, width = values, color = r, height = 0.8)

height = 0.8
for i, (value, url) in enumerate(zip(values, image_urls)):
    response = requests.get(url)
    img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))

    width, height = img.size
    left = 10
    top = 10
    right = width-10
    bottom = height-10
    im1 = img.crop((left, top, right, bottom)) 
    print(im1.size)
    im1

    ax.imshow(im1, extent = [value - 6, value, i - height / 2, i + height / 2], aspect = 'auto', zorder = 2)
```

Edit 2:

```
height = 0.8
for j, (value, url) in enumerate(zip(ww, image_urls)):
    response = requests.get(url)
    img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
    ax.imshow(img, extent = [value - 6, value - 2, j - height / 2, j + height / 2], aspect = 'auto', zorder = 2)

ax.set_xlim(0, max(ww)*1.05)
ax.set_ylim(-0.5, len(yy) - 0.5)
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like the answer is very similar to [Add image annotations to bar plots axis tick labels](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44246650/7758804)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need the images in a `.png` format with a transparent background. (Software such as Gimp or [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) could help in case the images don't already have the desired background.)

With such an image, [`plt.imshow()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html) can place it in the plot. The location is given via `extent=[x0, x1, y0, y1]`. To prevent `imshow` to force an equal aspect ratio, add `aspect='auto'`. `zorder=2` helps to get the image on top of the bars. Afterwards, the `plt.xlim` and `plt.ylim` need to be set explicitly (also because `imshow` messes with them.)

The example code below used 'ada.png' as that comes standard with matplotlib, so the code can be tested standalone. Now it is loading flags from [countryflags.io](https://www.countryflags.io), following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391945/how-do-i-read-image-data-from-a-url-in-python).

Note that the image gets placed into a box in [data coordinates](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html) (6 wide and 0.9 high in this case). This box will get stretched, for example when the plot gets resized. You might want to change the 6 to another value, depending on the x-scale and on the figure size.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
import requests
from io import BytesIO

labels = ['CW', 'CV', 'GW', 'SX', 'DO']
colors = ['crimson', 'dodgerblue', 'teal', 'limegreen', 'gold']
values = 30 + np.random.randint(5, 20, len(labels)).cumsum()

height = 0.9
plt.barh(y=labels, width=values, height=height, color=colors, align='center')

for i, (label, value) in enumerate(zip(labels, values)):
    # load the image corresponding to label into img
    # with cbook.get_sample_data('ada.png') as image_file:
    #    img = plt.imread(image_file)
    response = requests.get(f'https://www.countryflags.io/{label}/flat/64.png')
    img = plt.imread(BytesIO(response.content))
    plt.imshow(img, extent=[value - 8, value - 2, i - height / 2, i + height / 2], aspect='auto', zorder=2)
plt.xlim(0, max(values) * 1.05)
plt.ylim(-0.5, len(labels) - 0.5)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

PS: As explained by Ernest in the comments and in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44246650/automating-bar-charts-plotting-to-show-country-flags-as-ticklabels/44264051#44264051), using `OffsetImage` the aspect ratio of the image stays intact. (Also, the `xlim` and `ylim` stay intact.) The image will not shrink when there are more bars, so you might need to experiment with the factor in `OffsetImage(img, zoom=0.65)` and the x-offset in `AnnotationBbox(..., xybox=(-25, 0))`.

An extra option could place the flags outside the bar for bars that are too short. Or at the left of the y-axis.

The code adapted for horizontal bars could look like:

```py
import numpy as np
import requests
from io import BytesIO
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.offsetbox import OffsetImage, AnnotationBbox

def offset_image(x, y, label, bar_is_too_short, ax):
    response = requests.get(f'https://www.countryflags.io/{label}/flat/64.png')
    img = plt.imread(BytesIO(response.content))
    im = OffsetImage(img, zoom=0.65)
    im.image.axes = ax
    x_offset = -25
    if bar_is_too_short:
        x = 0
    ab = AnnotationBbox(im, (x, y), xybox=(x_offset, 0), frameon=False,
                        xycoords='data', boxcoords="offset points", pad=0)
    ax.add_artist(ab)

labels = ['CW', 'CV', 'GW', 'SX', 'DO']
colors = ['crimson', 'dodgerblue', 'teal', 'limegreen', 'gold']
values = 2 ** np.random.randint(2, 10, len(labels))

height = 0.9
plt.barh(y=labels, width=values, height=height, color=colors, align='center', alpha=0.8)

max_value = values.max()
for i, (label, value) in enumerate(zip(labels, values)):
    offset_image(value, i, label, bar_is_too_short=value < max_value / 10, ax=plt.gca())
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.15)
plt.show()
```

[image: example using <code>OffsetImage</code>]

Comment: I am getting the error "Image size of 191841060x533 pixels is too large. It must be less than 2^16 in each direction." I am using 44x44 images to plot.

Comment: I am reading the files from the internet 'https://www.countryflags.io/DO/flat/64.png'.

Comment: Thanks. The image size issue is fixed. I was not setting the limits for the axes. But now I see that the images are appearing slightly at the edge of the bars. What could be causing this?

Comment: You could experiment with the x-values in `extent=[ ...`. If your x-axis is like 300000, you could choose something like `extent=[value - 60000, value - 10000, ...`. An exact number is hard to set, because it would change as you add more bars, or the bars get longer or the figure changes.

Comment: Check existing Q&A. E.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44264051/4124317) would suggest to better use `OffsetImage` and thereby circumvent the data coordinates issue.

Comment: Using OffsetImage with annotationbbox, I am able to solve the dynamic coordinates issue, but now the flags go past the axis whenever the value reaches close to zero. How do I solve this? zorder?

Comment: the problem is that I have the value rendered in front of the bar.

Comment: I want to make it such that the image gets behind the axis. As in it just appears as a part of the bar.

Answer (score 2):

To complete @johanC answer, it's possible to use flags from `iso-flags-png` under GNU/linux and the `iso3166` python package:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from iso3166 import countries
import matplotlib.image as mpimg


def pos_image(x, y, pays, haut):
    pays = countries.get(pays).alpha2.lower()
    fichier = "/usr/share/iso-flags-png-320x240"
    fichier += f"/{pays}.png"
    im = mpimg.imread(fichier)
    ratio = 4 / 3
    w = ratio * haut
    ax.imshow(im,
              extent=(x - w, x, y, y + haut),
              zorder=2)


plt.style.use('seaborn')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

liste_pays = [('France', 10), ('USA', 9), ('Spain', 5), ('Italy', 5)]

X = [p[1] for p in liste_pays]
Y = [p[0] for p in liste_pays]

haut = .8
r = ax.barh(y=Y, width=X, height=haut, zorder=1)
y_bar = [rectangle.get_y() for rectangle in r]
for pays, y in zip(liste_pays, y_bar):
    pos_image(pays[1], y, pays[0], haut)


plt.show()
```

which gives:
[image]