# Plot an axes artist on a negative coordinate in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've been struggling with this for an hour and am still stumped... I would like to plot a series of 15 images (one for each row of a heatmap) and have code to do so:

```
from matplotlib.offsetbox import OffsetImage, AnnotationBbox

def getImage(path): 
    return OffsetImage(plt.imread(path),zoom=0.085)

for x0, y0, path in zip([0]*15,np.arange(0.5,15.5,1),paths):
    ab = AnnotationBbox(getImage(path), (x0, y0), frameon=False, fontsize=4)
    ax.add_artist(ab)
```

Since my x coordinates is list of 15 0s, my plot generates as such (not all 15 logos shown):

[image]

I would like to move the images to the left a bit more so they don't overlap the actual heatmap and are nicely aligned like a text label would be. However, if I change the x coordinate to something less than 0 (or anything outside of the axes bound it appears), the plot generates but all the images are absent. Are you not allowed to add axes artists to negative coordinates? I found out there is an `add_artist()` for the figure class, but when I try to use that instead of `ax` I get an error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'transData'
```

So, does anyone know how I could plot these logos just a bit to the left using `ax.add_artist()`?

**EDIT:** After looking through the code of the accepted answer, I realized the `xybox` param of my annotation box will solve my problem. Thus, the following loop works correclty:

```
for x0, y0, path in zip([0]*15,np.arange(0.5,15.5,1),paths):
    ab = AnnotationBbox(getImage(path), (x0, y0), xybox=(-.4,y0), frameon=False, fontsize=4)
    ax.add_artist(ab)
```

But the accepted answer's way of going about it also works correctly.

Comment: How did you create `ax`?  Are you sure every `path` in `paths` leads to a valid image?

Comment: I created the `ax` with `fig, ax = plt.subplots(...)` and yes I'm sure about the paths. `paths` is just a list of the path for each image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I adapted @JohanC's excellent response to your assignment, which you commented on. He should be the one to respond, but I will do so out of respect. Align the axis of the graph with the object from which the image was loaded. Set the position of the annotation box to a negative value based on the graph data. Add the annotation box to the artist. The heatmap data is obtained from the [official reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61971090/how-can-i-add-images-to-bars-in-axes-matplotlib) and the team logos from the Premier League.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.offsetbox import OffsetImage, AnnotationBbox

vegetables = ["cucumber", "tomato", "lettuce", "asparagus",
              "potato", "wheat", "barley"]
farmers = ["Farmer Joe", "Upland Bros.", "Smith Gardening",
           "Agrifun", "Organiculture", "BioGoods Ltd.", "Cornylee Corp."]

teams = ['manchester-city','liverpool','chelsea','arsenal','manchester-united',
         'west-ham-united','tottenham-hotspur-fc']

harvest = np.array([[0.8, 2.4, 2.5, 3.9, 0.0, 4.0, 0.0],
                    [2.4, 0.0, 4.0, 1.0, 2.7, 0.0, 0.0],
                    [1.1, 2.4, 0.8, 4.3, 1.9, 4.4, 0.0],
                    [0.6, 0.0, 0.3, 0.0, 3.1, 0.0, 0.0],
                    [0.7, 1.7, 0.6, 2.6, 2.2, 6.2, 0.0],
                    [1.3, 1.2, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.2, 5.1],
                    [0.1, 2.0, 0.0, 1.4, 0.0, 1.9, 6.3]])

def add_image(x, y, teams, ax):
    print('./data/premier_logos/{}-logo-vector.png'.format(teams))
    img = plt.imread('./data/premier_logos/{}-logo-vector.png'.format(teams))
    im = OffsetImage(img, zoom=0.085)
    im.image.axes = ax
    x_offset = -25
    ab = AnnotationBbox(im, (x,y), xybox=(x_offset,0), frameon=False, 
                        xycoords='data', boxcoords='offset points', pad=0)
    ax.add_artist(ab)
    
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(harvest)

# Show all ticks and label them with the respective list entries
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(farmers)), labels=farmers)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(len(vegetables)), labels='')

# Rotate the tick labels and set their alignment.
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha="right",
         rotation_mode="anchor")

# Loop over data dimensions and create text annotations.
for i in range(len(vegetables)):
    for j in range(len(farmers)):
        text = ax.text(j, i, harvest[i, j],
                       ha="center", va="center", color="w")

for i,t in enumerate(teams):
    add_image(0, i, t, ax=plt.gca())

ax.set_title("Harvest of local farmers (in tons/year)")
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @JohanC for your excellent response.

Comment: Wow, turns out all I needed to do was add `xybox=(-.3,y0)` to the `AnnotationBbox` inside my loop to get this to work. I discovered this by looking at your code, and your version does work as well, so I will mark it as the correct answer. Thanks!