# Matplotlib add SVG to axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, svg

I want to have flags next to country names, kind of like [Add image annotations to bar plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44246650/add-image-annotations-to-bar-plots), or in [How can I add images to bars in axes (matplotlib)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61971090/how-can-i-add-images-to-bars-in-axes-matplotlib).

I just want the flag to be right next to its name (I want it to have the ability to be chosen if to the right, left, on top or under).

The big problem that I have is that I want to do this with SVGs. Is there a simple way to group an SVGs with text so that it auto-aligns?

In the previous links I mentioned, it does it pretty good, but it does it with pngs not with svgs. I have also used Skunk (https://pypi.org/project/skunk/) but it doesn't really let you auto-align, it kind of just puts the SVG down and you have to manually align things.